# Python 3.4 HTTP Error 505 retrieving json from url

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am trying to connect to a page that takes in some values and return some data in JSON format in Python 3.4 using urllib. I want to save the values returned from the json into a csv file.

This is what I tried...

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = 'my_link/select?wt=json&indent=true&f=value'
response = urllib.request.Request(url)    
response = urllib.request.urlopen(response)
data = response.read()
```

I am getting an error below:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported
```

EDIT: Found a solution to my problem. I answered it below.

Answer (score 1):

You have found a server that apparently doesn't want to talk HTTP/1.1. You could try lying to it by claiming you are using a HTTP/1.0 client instead, by patching the `http.client.HTTPConnection` class:

```
import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
```

and re-trying your request.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running this script behind a vpn. Is that why I am getting this error?

Comment: @Cryssie if your VPN includes a transparent proxy, perhaps. Hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your input helped me look at other ways to communicate with the server and I found fancyURLopener which worked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I used FancyURLopener and it worked. Found this useful: [docs.python.org: urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

```
url_request = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
with url_request.open(url) as url_opener:
        json_data = url_opener.read().decode('utf-8')
        with open(file_output, 'w', encoding ='utf-8') as output:
            output.write(json_data)
```

Hope this helps those having the same problems as mine.